# Cleanup before exiting Java application

Tags: java, swing, nio

I'm writing a small Java application using Swing.
The application also has a networking component.

I want to run some code before exiting(close channels, keys, etc).Is there a way to do this, without adding an Exit button in my interface, in which to do my cleanup, then do System.exit()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want in `windowClosing()`, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143965).

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`Runtime#addShutdownHook`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) function to add a function to run when the JVM shuts down.

Comment: IMO this is the best answer... windowClosing() will not be called if your application is set to EXIT instead of DISPOSE on window close. It is not guaranteed to be called in all cases, and so is not as effective for guaranteeing your resources will be cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

'Close keys': SelectionKeys? You don't need to do anything about those. Closing the channel cancels all its SelectionKeys automatically. And unless you have pending data you need to flush you don't really need to close Channels either, the OS will do that for you.

Comment: I think I had some pending data or something, because I would get some weird behaviour on multiple runs of the application.Now that I do proper cleanup, it seems to be back to normal.